# Do the people of Kioka follow the Alderan religion?

Tags: alderamin-on-the-sky

In *Tenkyou no Alderamin*, the Katjvarna Empire (where Ikta and friends live) has as its state religion the Alderan religion. In episode 10, we learn that they aren't the only such state - the "home" of the religion is actually a theocracy lying to the north of the Empire (which reminds me quite a bit of the Papal States).

What of the Republic of Kioka, which lies to the east of the Empire? Do they also follow the Alderan religion? We know that they make use of the sprites, but - as demonstrated by the Sinack people - sprite worship does not necessarily imply veneration of Alderamin. (I guess there isn't anything to say that the people of Kioka even worship the sprites - they could just as well see them as friendly little bioweapons.)